# Angular doesn't update UI when a variable is changed

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble with rerendering in angular.

I have a dialog with a next and previous button that both call the same method that put a "isLoading" variable to true, get the next or previous element, then put isLoading to false again. On the HTML part i have an ngif in a mat-spinner to show it when isLoading is true.
The process of getting the next element and coloring it can take up to 1 second, but i can't see the mat spinner on the HTML, it looks like it doesn't refresh the UI when changing isLoading.

The only way i managed to make it work was to put a setTimeout around my whole method (exept for the isLoading = true) with a 1 ms delay, but i feel like this is awful, i would like to find a proper way to do this.

the current code :

```
  this.isLoading = true;
setTimeout(() => {
  let loopSequenceNumber;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.executedSplited.length; i++) {
    const element = this.executedSplited[i];
    if (element === this.currentSequenceNumber.toString()) {
      isForward ? loopSequenceNumber = this.executedSplited[i + 1] : loopSequenceNumber = this.executedSplited[i - 1];
        this.traceGraph.colorExecutedActivities(loopSequenceNumber + '', true);  
    }
  }
  this.setCurrentSequenceNumber(loopSequenceNumber);
  this.isLoading = false;
}, 1);
```

I have created a stackblitz to show the problem in a simpler way : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-grk4zx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks in advance for any help !

edit:
I found out about the changedetector and tried as well but it's the same thing : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-md18ne

Comment: hi! which version of angular are you using ?

Comment: Could you please provide some code on stackblitz.com to reproduce your issue?

Comment: In a synchronous function, it is a normal behavior because the change detection will be run at the end of the function. This is also why it "works" with a timeout. But imho, the real problem is that it takes up to 1s to find the next element. Can't you store the index of the currently selected element, so that you could just select i+1/i-1 ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle in fact it's not to find the index that takes time but it's the colorExecutedActivities, anyway i should be able to show a  spinner to the user.
I've created a new method next to the first that's only job is to toggle the isLoading and even tho it's a whole other method, the change detection doesn't seem to kick in:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-41cwdc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @MathKimRobin Hello i'm using the verison 8.2.14

Comment: @MernaMustafa Hello i've create a simple recreation you can see that while the console is logging the numbers the div isn't visible: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-grk4zx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts